# Eulers identity history

Tags: soft-question, math-history

When Euler discovered/invented $e^{ix} = \cos(x)+i\sin(x)$. Did he doubt his calculations for a length of time? Was it Readily accepted by the mathematical community quickly or did they object at first? If so when was it finally accepted and why?

Comment: [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with power series was innovated by James Gregory and Isaac Newton almost a century earlier so the kind of arguments Euler presented in his 1748 *Introductio* were easily digestible by his contemporary mathematicians.  The *Introductio* is full of calculations with power series a lot more complicated than the one you mentioned.  I have seen no evidence that anybody doubted Euler's formula. His infinite product formula for the sine function was far more innovative; that also seems to have elicited no objections. For a detailed study of the formula see for example [this acticle](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.00455).

Comment: Other than the his work on the Basil problem are there any large contributions he made that were harshly doubted?

Comment: In chapter 3 of the *Introductio* there is a lengthy discussion of the philosophical foundations of the infinitesimal method.  This may have been a reaction to Georg Berkeley's criticism or to criticisms by other authors.  However, Berkeley explicitly stated that he is not criticizing the *results* of infinitesimal calculus; Rolle tried that thirty years earlier, and was greatly embarrassed as a result when his own mistakes were exposed. Rather, Berkeley objected on philosophical grounds; the same kind of objections resurfaced in Cantor a century and a half later, and can still be seen on...

Comment: ...SME today; see for example [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787094/first-year-calculus-student-why-isnt-the-derivative-the-slope-of-a-secant-line/1787661#1787661) and the comments following.

Comment: Cant edit comment but I want it noted for math's history. Basil is an herb. Basel is a city with a great problem named after it.

Comment: :-) The formula for sine as an infinite product also provides a proof of the Basel problem; see that article. @shai

Comment: My Gf will be pissed at me for reading about 100 year old math instead of spending time with her but fundamentals are important, you know?