# How to derive the triple product rule with Nonstandard Analysis?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, nonstandard-analysis

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -1$ according to the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule)
However, it would be 1, if derivatives behaved like fractions.

And in [Nonstandard Calculus](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Ekeisler/calc.html) derivatives do behave like fractions. (it treats derivatives as fractions of actual infinitesimal quantities, rather than d/dx applied to a function)

So, how does Nonstandard Calculus get the correct answer here? 
(which it must since it is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51453/is-non-standard-analysis-worth-learning) to standard calculus)

Comment: The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule has a derivation that may help. It doesn't use limits explicitly, so it might be compatible with non-standard calculus.

Comment: I believe that the two $\partial x$'s are different infinitesimals in a nonstandard treatment  (and similar for the other variables) as they relate to different increments when different variables are held fixed. It is basically the same issue as the classical setting; the Leibniz notation just invites blurring these lines in both cases. This (or a related simplified version) is probably somewhere in Chapter 11 of the linked Keisler text.

Comment: @leslietownes Is there a simple way to keep track of that? I'm hoping that Nonstandard analysis provides a framework to easily find the answer to such things. Issues like this one are often quoted as the reason why d/dx is not a fraction. Yet so many proofs in physics are cavalier with d/dx "fractions". Occasionally that comes back to bite, as it does here. If the solution here is elegant, then I'd be convinced [nonstandard analysis is worth learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51453/is-non-standard-analysis-worth-learning)